# What is it called the blue highlighted word that helps filling up the form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how it is being implemented and what is the feature called? I tried googling but I cannot find the specific name.

One example is at airbnb website [AirBnB Website](https://www.airbnb.com/)

It is when you try to fill in the city and the suggested city is appended with blue highlight.

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete? The color depends on your OS, browser, etc.

Comment: Its called auto-complete suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called autocomplete or typeahead. A library detects your input and gives you related suggestions. Have a look at [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), a library for typeaheads.